# Java - JTextArea refuses to print strings that are just whitespace

Tags: java, string, swing, fonts, jtextarea

I have written a command terminal using Swing components. The snippets of code below contain everything I think could be part of the problem. What is happening is in Snippet #1, when I call printBoard(), it ignores the whitespace in the values[][] array. I tried switching to String[][] instead of char[][] but it didn't work.

If you need more information, please ask. Thanks for your help!

EDIT: https://github.com/GlitchGamer1459/Windows-Command-Prompt-Clone

Snippet #1:

```
package Application.play;

import Application.control.Controller;
import Application.control.IOEngine;
import Application.control.Terminal;

public class TicTacToe {

    private static final IOEngine stringMethods = new IOEngine();

    private static char charToPrint = 'X';

    @SuppressWarnings("FieldMayBeFinal")
    private static char[][] values = {
            { ' ', ' ', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ' }
    };

    private static void printBoard() {
        Terminal.out.println(" " + values[0][0] + " | " + values[0][1] + " | " + values[0][2] + " ");
        Terminal.out.println("---+---+---");
        Terminal.out.println(" " + values[1][0] + " | " + values[1][1] + " | " + values[1][2] + " ");
        Terminal.out.println("---+---+---");
        Terminal.out.println(" " + values[2][0] + " | " + values[2][1] + " | " + values[2][2] + " ");
    }

    private static void parseChain(String chain) { // a chain looks like this: '1.1' or this: '0.2'
        try {
            int vertical = Integer.parseInt(stringMethods.getUntilFirst('.', chain));
            int horizontal = Integer.parseInt(stringMethods.getUntilSecond('.', chain));

            if (charToPrint == 'X') {
                charToPrint = 'O';
            } else {
                charToPrint = 'X';
            }

            values[vertical][horizontal] = charToPrint;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            Terminal.out.println("Not A Valid Input, try again");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Terminal.out.println("Not A Valid Input, must be within range of 0-2");
        }
    }

    public static void runGame(String string) {
        Controller.ioEngine.clearTerminalScreen();
        parseChain(string);
        printBoard();
    }

    public static void start() {
        Terminal.setActiveCycle(2);
    }
}
```

Snippet #2:

```
package Application.control;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Out {
    JTextArea outputScreen;

    public Out(JTextArea outputArea) {
        outputScreen = outputArea;
    }

    public void println() {
        outputScreen.append("\n");
    }

    public void println(String output) {
        outputScreen.append(output + "\n");
    }

    public void println(double output) {
        outputScreen.append(output + "\n");
    }

    public void println(int output) {
        outputScreen.append(output + "\n");
    }

    public void println(char output) {
        outputScreen.append(output + "\n");
    }

    public void println(float output) {
        outputScreen.append(output + "\n");
    }
}
```

Snippet #3:

```
package Application.terminal;

import Application.control.Controller;
import Application.control.Terminal;
import Application.play.GuessGame;
import Application.play.TicTacToe;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class EventHandler implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    public boolean gameAlreadyInit = false;

    //KeyListener methods
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 10) {
            String input = Controller.terminal.inputField.getText();
            Controller.terminal.inputField.setText("");
            switch (Terminal.getActiveCycle()) {
                case 0 -> // runs the base Terminal cycle
                    Controller.ioEngine.parseInput(input);
                case 1 -> { // runs the guessing game
                    if (!gameAlreadyInit) {
                        GuessGame.start();
                        gameAlreadyInit = true;
                    }

                    GuessGame.runGame(input);
                }
                case 2 -> {
                    if (!gameAlreadyInit) {
                        TicTacToe.start();
                        gameAlreadyInit = true;
                    }

                    TicTacToe.runGame(input);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    //ActionListener methods
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your issue is more likely related to the font you're using

Comment: `outputScreen.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 15));` this is the font I had

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I pulled your code, and ignoring the over use of `static`, `null` layouts and `KeyListener`, I changed:

```
outputScreen.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
```

to

```
outputScreen.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 15));
```

and it now prints

[image]

You need to make use of a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) in order to ensure that all the characters have equal widths

Also, you should follow Andrew's advice...

```
outputScreen.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 15));
```

Now you get platform independence.

> what's wrong with the null layout?

Without a layout manager...

[image]

With a layout manager...

[image]

Resiability for free.  You also don't have to worry about the DPI or what things like accessibility might do.

`null` or "pixel perfect" layouts are an illusion. To many factor go into determining how a component should be sized and how components should be laid out in relationship to each other.

A lot of work has gone into solving these issues, Swing makes use of layout managers, other frameworks do similar things.

Rather then spending a lot of time tearing your hair out over why the layout breaks on some others computer, just make use of the layout managers that are already available to you - for example, `BorderLayout` would be a fantastic for your current layout

> what's wrong with KeyListener?

`KeyListener` is too low level a API for your needs.  Since all you're doing is monitoring for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key anyway, you might as well make use of the `ActionListener` support.  You're also assuming the key code is constant.

If you want to filter the input, then you should use a `DocumentFilter`.

Comment: I'm still new to fonts, and swing in general, so thanks for your help! If you don't mind me asking, what's wrong with the null layout and KeyListener?

Comment: `outputScreen.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 15));` better to use the constant than presume `Courier` is available (and the default monospaced font the user would expect to see). So I'd change that to: `outputScreen.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 15));`

Comment: `null` layouts or "pixel perfect" layouts are an illusion.  To many factor go into determining how a component should be sized and how components should be laid out in relationship to each other.  A lot of work has gone into solving these issues, Swing makes use of layout managers, other frameworks do similar things. Rather then spending a lot of time tearing your hair out over why the layout breaks on some others computer, just make use of the layout managers that are already available to you - for example, `BorderLayout` would be a fantastic for your current layout

Comment: As for `KeyListener`, the only thing you monitoring is the return key, but not all systems might use [Enter] as the "return" or "input" key.  Instead, use a `ActionListener`, it's what it's designed for